# Dynamic hashing [caching]

Tags: algorithm, hash

Regardless of the programming language, I wonder if what I am about to implement is not bad. I have millions of int64 ID and double values to store in a hash table. I want to try some sort of  dynamic hashing first. This is what I am thinking:

- To try a fixed size (i.e. 100K) hash of form `<hashedID, value>` and for each cell
  of this hash table I store another hastable which contains the same
  hash key and a list, something like this: `<hashedID, [ID,count]>`.
- Assume that ID_1 is the residing element in a particular cell of the first and second hash table. Now for a newly arrived entry, if it hashes to the same hashedID, I check: if it has the same ID as the existing ID_1 (which I check via the second hash table), if yes then I increase the count. If it doesn't, then I decrease the count. If the count was 0 after decreasing the count, I would replace it with the ID that just arrived.

This way I hope to have the popular stuff to stay in the first hash table.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me a bit of the move-to-front heuristic for hash tables with external chaining - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table says "If the load factor is large and some keys are more likely to come up than others, then rearranging the chain with a move-to-front heuristic may be effective. More sophisticated data structures, such as balanced search trees, are worth considering only if the load factor is large (about 10 or more), or if the hash distribution is likely to be very non-uniform, or if one must guarantee good performance even in a worst-case scenario. However, using a larger table and/or a better hash function may be even more effective in those cases". See also http://www.seg.rmit.edu.au/code/zwh-ipl/.

If k entries hash to the same slot, only one of them can be the favoured entry that gets a fast lookup, so if they all have roughly the same probability of being searched on, making the most popular one take 0 time will gain you a factor of only k/(k-1).

If you are interested in implementing slightly non-standard hash table routines, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing might be worth a look.